# Elastic Search / Hibernate Search : how to code xor operator with query DSL API in java?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, hibernate-search

I'am using hibernate search java API to generate an elastic search query. I have problem to code a xor operator. Typically I wrote :

```
private void applyXorOperator(BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> boolClausesAppender,
                                  BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> firstBool,
                                  BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> secondBool) {

        boolClausesAppender.should(
        boolClausesAppender.must(firstBool).mustNot(secondBool));
        boolClausesAppender.should(
                boolClausesAppender.mustNot(firstBool).must(secondBool));
        boolClausesAppender.minimumShouldMatchNumber(1);
    }
```

How do I say "not both", I was expecting :

```
boolClausesAppender.maximumShouldMatchNumber(1);
```

but this method doesn't exist in the API. Any solution ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition:

```
a XOR b <=> (a AND NOT b) OR (NOT a AND b)
```

So just implement it that way:

```java
private void applyXorOperator(BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> boolClausesAppender,
                                  BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> firstBool,
                                  BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> secondBool) {
    SearchPredicate a = firstBool.toPredicate();
    SearchPredicate b = secondBool.toPredicate();

    boolClausesAppender.should(f -> f.bool()
         // a AND NOT b
         .should(f.bool().must(a).mustNot(b))
         // OR (NOT a AND b)
         .should(f.bool().mustNot(a).must(b)));
}
```

EDIT: By the way, you don't need first/second to be boolean predicates. This would work too, and seems simpler:

```java
private void applyXorOperator(BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> boolClausesAppender,
                                  PredicateFinalStep first,
                                  PredicateFinalStep second) {
    SearchPredicate a = first.toPredicate();
    SearchPredicate b = second.toPredicate();

    boolClausesAppender.should(f -> f.bool()
         // a AND NOT b
         .should(f.bool().must(a).mustNot(b))
         // OR (NOT a AND b)
         .should(f.bool().mustNot(a).must(b)));
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer. It's right I did a mistake, the formula already includes "not both", I was wondering for nothing ;).