"Either one or the other" predicate with QueryDSL
I need to create this kind of query with QueryDSL and JPA:
I want all entities X where X.property is either valueY or valueZ.
(ValueZ should only be returned when there is no X.property equal to valueY, so I do not expect the union of valueY and valueZ, valueZ should be the default)
To Do that I made this kind of predicate with a sub-query:
var x = QX.x;
var anotherX = new QX("anotherX");

var predicate = x.property.eq("valueY").or(x.property.eq("valueZ")
  .and(JPAExpressions.select(anotherX)
  .from(anotherX)
  .where(anotherX.property.eq("valueY")).notExists()));

Is there a simpler approach with query DSL?
If not, do you think it would worth to add such "either" feature to it? (Adding extra arguments to either, with for example a path/value to an aggregation key for valueY existence test...)

Not sure if there is a feature in QueryDSL to do this, but at least for your question title: you are looking for an Xor, which means "x or y but not x AND y". Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312615/elastic-search-hibernate-search-how-to-code-xor-operator-with-query-dsl-api?

Yep I thought the same also, but xor does bot seem to fit well with this default value...(changed the title)
